# Proper way to assign watermark with DateStreamSource<List<T>> using Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a continuing JSONArray data produced to Kafka topic,and I wanna process records with EventTime characteristic.In order to reach this goal,I have to assign watermark to each record which contained in the JSONArray.

I didn't find a convenience way to achieve this goal.My solution is consuming data from DataStreamSource> ,then iterate List and collect Object to downstream with an anonymous ProcessFunction,finally assign watermark to the this downstream.

The major code shows below:

`DataStreamSource<List<MockData>> listDataStreamSource = KafkaSource.genStream(env);
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<MockData> convertToPojo = listDataStreamSource
        .process(new ProcessFunction<List<MockData>, MockData>() {
          @Override
          public void processElement(List<MockData> value, Context ctx, Collector<MockData> out)
              throws Exception {
            value.forEach(mockData -> out.collect(mockData));
          }
        });
    convertToPojo.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<MockData>(Time.seconds(5)) {
          @Override
          public long extractTimestamp(MockData element) {
            return element.getTimestamp();
          }
        });
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Long>> countStream = convertToPojo
        .keyBy("country").window(
            SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(10)))
        .process(
            new FlinkEventTimeCountFunction()).name("count elements");`

The code seems all right without doubt,running without error as well.But ProcessWindowFunction never triggered.I tracked the Flink source code,find EventTimeTrigger never returns TriggerResult.FIRE,causing by TriggerContext.getCurrentWatermark returns Long.MIN_VALUE all the time.

What's the proper way to process List in eventtime?Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying the keyBy and window operations to the convertToPojo stream, rather than the stream with timestamps and watermarks (which you didn't assign to a variable).

If you write the code more or less like this, it should work:

```
listDataStreamSource = KafkaSource ...
convertToPojo = listDataStreamSource.process ...
pojoPlusWatermarks = convertToPojo.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks ...
countStream = pojoPlusWatermarks.keyBy ...
```

Calling assignTimestampsAndWatermarks on the convertToPojo stream does not modify that stream, but rather creates a new datastream object that includes timestamps and watermarks. You need to apply your windowing to that new datastream.

Comment: Very glad to see you,and thanks for you prompt reply .I don't quite understand that,is it means user can not assign watermark to down stream other than source stream.As I find SourceFunction has collectWithTimestamp but none in Collector.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Your precise explanation enlightened me,following your guide and pseudocode,it works well now.